# fontinst and italic small caps

Tags: fonts, small-caps, italic, berry

I have a font that is distributed with italic small caps. I'd like to use these with fontinst. Does the current release of fontinst support italic small caps, and if so, what Karl Berry name should I use for the font so that it will be recognized by fontinst? (note: I am intending on using the font with pdflatex and not xelatex!)

Answer (score 2):

In fontinst, you can always program whatever you want, but `\latinfamily` to the best of my knowledge does not support italic small caps.

About the actual font names: in the 'short' Karl Berry scheme, there is no way to have smallcaps other than upright (which in turn is likely why it is not supported by fontinst).

In the new 'long names' system, you could write something like this:

```
Monotype-Minion-Regular-Smallcaps=Italic-Regular-Adobe--10.tfm
```

but as fontinst does not understand such names, I don't think that helps much, and you could as well stick to the vendor naming.

Comment: It is simply not true that you cannot name them in the Karl Berry scheme. `ci` is appropriate for italic small-caps. The scheme allows multiple variants to be combined. Using vendor naming would be bad. Using one of the standard naming schemes increases the chances that you can access the non-standard variant using a standard support file (e.g. fontaxes or nfssext-cfr). Using the vendor name pretty much guarantees that won't work and isn't an option anyway, since you have to re-encode them which means new names.